# numpy 配列の要素を取り出して個別の変数に代入したい

Tags: python, numpy

`model_lr.coef_ = array([[0.90157393 0.20698037]])` の場合、以下のように代入したい。

```
a1 = 0.90157393
a2 = 0.20698037
```

`a1, a2 = model_lr.coef_` ではうまくいかないので、どうすればいいか知りたいです。

Comment: `a1, a2 = model_lr.coef_[0]` でよい様な。

Comment: [[0.90157393 0.20698037]]－＞[0.90157393 0.20698037]であるのが正解ですかね